# Proving the converse of Radical Axis

Tags: geometry

Given two circles with centers $A$ and $B$, with no common points internally, draw the line $AB$. The point $P$ on $AB$ has equal tangent length to circles $A$ and $B$. Construct the perpendicular to $AB$ at $P$, and pick an arbitrary point on the perpendicular.
How do I show that this point will have equal length tangents as well? I have tried using power of a point, but I haven't come to anything of use.

Comment: soybean farming in kyrgyzstan

Comment: aidotu5yew9rvuu